# Prevent Gravity Forms submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to prevent Gravity Forms (Wordpress) form from being submitted and pass field values to the simplest javascript instead. But somehow it just doesn't work.

I've tryed:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gform_1").submit(function(event) { // gform_1 - id of the form
        alert('Fired!');
        return false;
    });
});
```

But it's not getting triggered - form still gets submitted and I can see that confirmation message. Can you tell me, what's wrong?

Just to be clear: I don't want to see those entries in my database, I don't want to my form being removed and see that confirmation message etc (that's why I'm not using hooks like gform_post_submission). I just want to use some form data in my script. Is it possible and how? Thanks in advance!

edit: Got this sorted out: the script was inside a post, so I had to use "jQuery("#gform_1")" instead of "$("#gform_1")".

Comment: you can try HTML <input> disabled Attribute ??

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't edit HTML.

Comment: did you try 

 event.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes, with the same result.